# XML/XSLT nested loop of attributes to produce HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to produce a HTML table from some XML I have got through a SQL query. The XML produced looks like the following:

```
<root>
<form attribute1="1" attribute2="1" />
<form attribute1="1" attribute2="2" />
<form attribute1="1" attribute2="3" />
<form attribute1="2" attribute2="1" />
<form attribute1="2" attribute2="2" />
<form attribute1="3" attribute2="1" />
</root>
```

The table I am trying to produce needs to have a header row for each unique attribute1 with rows underneath for each attribute2, something like this:

```
<attribute1="1" />
<attribute2="1" />
<attribute2="2" />
<attribute2="3" />

<attribute1="2" />
<attribute2="1" />
<attribute2="2" />

<attribute1="3" />
<attribute2="1" />
```

I don't have much experience using XML/XSLT but I am hoping it would be possible to do something like loop through the forms, create a header row for each unique attribute1 then create data rows associated to the unique attribute1 underneath.

Comment: This is a "grouping" issue. If you are using XSLT 1.0 you will need to use a technique called Muenchian grouping. See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html for an explanation. In this case, your key would be `<xsl:key name="form" match="form" use="@attribute1" />`. If you are using XSLT 2.0 though, you can use `xsl:for-each-group`. See http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html.

Comment: Hi @Tim-C. I am pretty sure that I am using 1.0 only so I will have to look into the Muenchian grouping. For my understanding, this will give each of the rows a key depending on the attribute1. So to then carry on with the processing, I would need to `<xsl:for-each select="key('form', @attribute1)>` to get the header row then inside that do `<xsl:for-each select="@attribute2">` to get the data rows?

Comment: I've added an answer to show Muenchian grouping in action for your example.

Comment: @DavidAustin Please post your expected output **as code**.

Comment: @TimC Many thanks, I will have to try that out but I think I understand what is going on. First create the key based on attribute1, then for each key id, create a header row then apply the form template which inserts rows for each of the attribute2 rows.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have edited my OP, I hope it is okay now. I don't really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use XSLT 1.0, try this XSLT for starters, which uses the Muenchian Grouping method

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="form" match="form" use="@attribute1" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- Get first "form" element that occurs in each group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="form[generate-id() = generate-id(key('form',@attribute1)[1])]">
          <group>
            <header><xsl:value-of select="@attribute1" /></header>
            <!-- Get the "form" elements that make up the group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('form', @attribute1)" />
          </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="form">
    <row><xsl:value-of select="@attribute2" /></row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's some XSLT that can create an HTML table. This one is slightly more advanced as it works out the maximum number of columns for a row, and uses that in creating colspan attributes for the shorter rows

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="form" match="form" use="@attribute1" />

    <xsl:variable name="maxCells">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/form[generate-id() = generate-id(key('form',@attribute1)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="count(key('form', @attribute1))" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('form', @attribute1))" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <table border="1">
        <!-- Get first "form" element that occurs in each group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="form[generate-id() = generate-id(key('form',@attribute1)[1])]">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="{$maxCells}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@attribute1" />
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <!-- Get the "form" elements that make up the group -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('form', @attribute1)" />
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="form">
    <td>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="$maxCells - count(key('form', @attribute1)) + 1" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@attribute2" />   
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @TimC. I can't get this to work - it needs to produce a html table at the end of it. I will edit my OP with the code I have tried adapted from yours.

Comment: @DavidAustin I've added a sample to my answer to show an HTML table being output.